# Generate all words using Java

Tags: java, string

I want to know how to generate all words using java from specified characters and length

```
String first[]={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
String second[]={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
String ch ="";  
String total[];

for(int i = 0;i<26;i++) {
    for(int j = 0;j<26;j++) {
        ch+=first[i]+first[j];
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
```

I get only 576 words only by this program, but the 26! words is 4.03291461 × 10^26

How to write the program in java?

Comment: Hasn't it the smell of homework ? If it is, please tag your message accordingly.

Comment: Your program prints out every 2-letter word possible.

Comment: yes my problem is my program display not correctly...

i want the following like

aa
ab
.
.
.
az
aac
.
.
aaz

then 
ba
.
.
bz

and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution. It's kind of quick, so don't be too hard on the optimization.

```
public static void printWords(int length) {

    if (length < 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    printWordsRec("", length);
}

private static void printWordsRec(String base, int length) {

    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
        if (length == 1) {
            System.out.println(base + c);
        }
        else {
            printWordsRec(base + c, length - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
public class Words {
    static char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

    static void generate(StringBuilder sb, int n) {
        if (n == sb.length()) {
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
            return;
        }
        for (char letter : alphabet) {
            sb.setCharAt(n, letter);
            generate(sb, n + 1);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int length = 2; length <= 5; length++) {
            sb.setLength(length);
            generate(sb, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

This generates all 2-letters, 3-letters, 4-letters, and 5-letters "words". It uses a standard recursive algorithm.

#### See also

- [Given an array of integers [x0 x1 x2], how do you calculate all possible permutations from [0 0 0] to [x0 x1 x2]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664800/given-an-array-of-integers-x0-x1-x2-how-do-you-calculate-all-possible-permutat/)

---

On a more mathematical note, people often confuse what the term "permutation" means. Yes, there are 26! permutations of the 26 letters `a-z` -- that's *A LOT* of strings, but this does not include `aa, ab`, etc. It includes all strings where the 26 letters each appear exactly once.

Answer (score 5):

Consider what you're doing:
you're looping through the first array once, and looping through the second once for each iteration through that loop.
That's going to yield you a total of 26^2 results, or 676 (not 576).
And the way you're constructing the output is very specific, check what you get and you'll notice a highly explicit pattern in there.

The second array of course is never used at all, so completely superfluous.

The solution is to write out on paper how you'd go about it were you to attempt it by hand, then attempt to translate that into code.
For one you're not going to want to have only words of a specific length (which you get) or specific patterns of letters (which you also get).

Comment: Good tip (without giving away the answer).

Answer (score 3):

> but the 26! words is 4.03291461 × 1026
>
> how to write the program in java

You **don't** write that program in Java or any other language. It would be pointless because it would literally take billions of years to finish.

But the number is also completely wrong for your intended result in the comments. 26! is the number of permutations, i.e. the different ways to order 26 elements *without* repetition. The number of words would be 26^n, where n is the length.

Comment: +1. I'm still baffled how OP can say "It's only this many, not [an astronomically large number]" so matter-of-factly. He wants to generate more strings than there are stars in the universe.

Comment: And huge amount of space. ~2.3 GB for all 4-length words in small characters.