# Generate All Possible Words of Length n

Tags: java

Given:

- Some characters in `input` String.
- An integer `N`

How can I generate all possible words that has the exact length of N?

If I have `input = {"a", "b", "a"}` and `N=2`, then the output should be: `ab,aa,ba` (without the duplicates)

---

I searched for this, and all I got is some algorithms that I couldn't understand rather that implement. I understand that I need to implement a recursive method, but I'm stuck at the point after the stop condition.

```
public void generate(String input, int length) {        
    if(length == 0) {
        System.out.println(input);
        return;
    }
    //Not sure about this part
    String[] a = input.split("");
    for(int i =0; i<a.length; i++) {
        loop(input+a[i], length-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What format do you want the results in? An array?

Comment: Have you looked [At this solution][1] ?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673494/generate-all-words-using-java?rq=1

Comment: @StephenTG Array is fine.

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk No. If acharacter is listed once then it can't appear twice.

Comment: @iturki you defined that input is a set, a set doesn't have repeats.

Comment: If there are K symbols and no restrictions then there are pow(K,L) words of length L.  This suggests a mapping from integers N=0..(pow(K,L)-1) into words where one finds the base K representation of a number N and then replaces the digits with the symbols.

Comment: @roippi Didn't meant that set. Fixed.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288836/given-a-length-and-a-set-of-characters-how-to-get-all-the-possible-string-combi/12288895#12288895) for generating the values, then use a `HashSet` to ignore duplicates.

Comment: Also a good resource: [Combinatorial Algorithms](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/combinatorial-algorithms.html)

Comment: @Brian This will take time if you have -as in my real case- a list of 12 chars and N can go up to 10!

Comment: Given the nature of your issue, I think most solutions are going to take quite a few iterations

Comment: @GabrielKohen This is the closest thing to my situation. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Brian Besides, I'm expecting inputs in all languages, not English only. So, iterating won't do it.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick and work with any `input` and `N`. Behavior is not well defined for `N = 0` or `N > input.length()`

```
public static void generate(String input, int N) {
    generate("", input, new HashSet<String>(), N);
}

private static void generate(String str, String input, Set<String> dup, int N) {
    if (str.length() == N && dup.add(str))
        System.out.println(str);
    else
        //remove a char form input and add it to str
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
            generate(
                str + input.charAt(i), 
                input.substring(0, i) + input.substring(i + 1), 
                dup, N);
}
```

This has been adapted from the more general "calculate all permutation" problem. In the general problem there is no duplicate check and `str` is printed when `input.isEmpty()`. Let me know if you need any clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

This works well also for empty strings or n == 0.

The heavylifting is in the second overload `combination()` method (the one that takes four parameters). The first overload simply translates the input string into a `List<Character>` and prepares an empty hash-set where the results are stored:

```
Set<String> combination(String input, int n) {
  List<Character> letters = new ArrayList<Character>();
  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i)
    letters.add(input.charAt(i));
  Set<String> results = new HashSet<String>();
  combination("", letters, n, results);
  return results;
}

void combination(String soFar, List<Character> letters, int n, 
    Set<String> results) {
  if (n == 0) { 
    results.add(soFar);
    return;
  }

  int startIndex = soFar.length();
  if (startIndex >= letters.size())
    return;      

  for (int i = startIndex; i < letters.size(); ++i) {
    // ch is the next candidate to add to the result that we're 
    // building (soFar)
    char ch = letters.get(i); 
    // Swap the characters at positions i and position startIndex.
    char temp = letters.get(startIndex);
    letters.set(i, temp);
    letters.set(startIndex, ch);

    // add ch to soFar, compute combinations of length n-1.
    // as startIndex is essentially soFar.length() this means that 
    // the recursive call will only process the remainder of the list.
    combination(soFar + ch, letters, n - 1, result);

    // Swap the characters back - restore the original state.
    letters.set(i, ch);
    letters.set(startIndex, temp);
  }
```